# Google Tag Manager, requirejs and the Aurelia CLI

Tags: requirejs, google-tag-manager, aurelia

I have an [Aurelia CLI](http://aurelia.io/hub#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli) application into which I'm trying to include de [Google Tag Manager](https://www.google.com/analytics/tag-manager/) scripts

```
<head>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <!--<script>
        var dataLayer = [];
        dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'hixo' });
    </script>
    <script>
        (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({
                'gtm.start':
                    new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
            }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                    j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src =
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-PLSZRC');
    </script>-->
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
</head>
```

But as soon as I start the application I get the following `requirejs` error:

```
"Mismatched anonymous define() modules"
```

The Aurelia CLI uses `requirejs`, but it is completely abstracted so, where and how should I define the Google Tag Manager Script so that it is not handled as an anonymous module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `dataLayer.push()` for the first time after loading the google tag manager script, GTM will load additional scripts. These scripts are loaded asynchronously, so these scripts will finish loading **after** the aurelia-cli bundle (and requirejs which is inside this bundle) has been loaded. This is why RequireJS is complaining of the anonymous define error, even though the GTM script tag is included **before** the aurelia-cli bundle.

One of the scripts loaded by Google Tag Manager is Fingerprint2 from [this URL](http://www.clickcease.com/monitor/stat.js). Currently this is version 1.4.1 of Fingerprint2, and in the GitHub repository there is [this issue](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2/issues/92) mentioning the same `Mismatched anonymous define()` error. It seems to be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2/pull/202), but since Google Tag Manager loads Fingerprint2 (and we can't override this behavior) we need a workaround to get it working.

A workaround is to load Fingerprint2 yourself synchronously using a script tag and then tell RequireJS to ignore the `Mismatched anonymous define()` error originating from Google Tag Manager loading Fingerprint2 the second time:

```
<script src="http://www.clickcease.com/monitor/stat.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
<script>
  requirejs.onError = function (err) {
    if (err.message.indexOf('Fingerprint2') === -1) {
      throw err;
    }
  };
</script>
```

Hopefully Clickcease will update their version of Fingerprint2 soon so that this workaround will no longer be necessary.